# Rx GroupByUntil with Throttling timer rebirth

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Rx `GroupByUntil` documentation states

> When a new element with the same key value as a reclaimed group occurs,
>   the group will be reborn with a new lifetime request.

I have a problem with this piece of code.

```
myObservable.GroupByUntil(
                    selectKey,
                    g => g.Throttle( selectTimer(g.Key),
                    throttlingScheduler))
```

My throttling timer `selectTimer` is not called when the group is "reborn" with a new element of same group key. Instead, element groupping continues with the same throttling timer.

Is there a way to refresh throttle timer when an element of same key-value occurs?

Comment: Are you saying that the first group expires (because it pauses long enough for its throttle timer to expire and release a value), and then sometime later another item with that key comes along and does not create a new group?

Comment: @Brandon not exactly. Imagine a group always exists. I want to be able to modify existing group's throttle timer on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding `GroupByUntil`.  It only calls the duration selector when it newly constructs a group.  When the observable returned by the duration selector produces a value, then it ends that group.  The next time an item arrives with that group key, it will create a new group (and call the duration selector again).

Sounds like your actual issue is with `Throttle`.  You want to know how to adjust the throttle timer on the fly.  Try the overload of `Throttle` which takes a throttle duration selector, which it calls each time a new item arrives.  Assuming `selectTimer` returns a `TimeSpan`:

```
g => g.Throttle(item => Observable.Timer(selectTimer(g.Key), throttlingScheduler))
```

Comment: Nice. Where can you find the documentation on this overload? MSDN does not seem to have it..

Comment: The MSDN documentation used to be the canonical source, but it's sadly no longer in sync with http://rx.codeplex.com. There are many features not in MSDN so I would use the codeplex site as your source. Discussion, samples and issues there can help - but personally I tend to rely on the source code and source history.

Comment: Note that "officially" the source and all issues were moved to GitHub: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET

Comment: Yeah Rx.Net documentation is not very good (unlike the excellent [RxJs documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/doc#reactive-extensions-class-library)).  I find that Visual Studio Intellisense is my Best Friend for finding different overloads.